# Search document all FARM SharePoint

Tags: development, search-results, custom

There is a document on the SharePoint server, its location is unknown, how can you find it using C#(.NET) without recourse to the search service, i.e. let's say I want to develop my custom search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to iterate through all of the objects:

```
SPFarm
   SPWebApplication
    SPSite (Site collections)
      SPWeb  (sites)
        SPList  (and filter for just libraries)
```

You would only be able to search in the document's metadata (name, created by, library columns, etc.) and not by keyword within the document. (Unless you want to open and parse the content of all of the files / file types.)

At the Site Collection level you use a SPSite​Data​Query CAML Query to search the Site Collection. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ms409088(v=office.15)

This would be very slow compared to a SharePoint Search. Why do you not want to call the Search API?

Comment: I too am curious. There was a comparison paper done several years ago comparing data access methods. Search was something like 58 times faster than enumeration for a small farm.

Comment: Mike thanks you, tell me, why can't I search inside documents by keywords? use for example library Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word?